# How to specify a C library dependency for Houston?

Tags: appcenter

I am writing an application that depends on [GCrypt](https://valadoc.org/gcrypt/GCrypt.html), which is a C library. Its development headers can be found in Ubuntu repos in the `libgcrypt20-dev` package (or the older `libgcrypt11-dev`).

Running a meson build locally works correctly, but on Houston, it fails with the following error:

```
meson.build:36:0: ERROR:  C library 'libgcrypt' not found
```

I tried specifying both these packages in the .travis.yml file so that it builds (and it does indeed install those packages) but the same error occurs in all scenarios.

- [Complete log](https://travis-ci.com/github/elfenware/obliviate/builds/209559518)
- [.travis.yml](https://github.com/elfenware/obliviate/blob/main/.travis.yml)
- [meson.build](https://github.com/elfenware/obliviate/blob/main/meson.build)

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by specifying the dependency in debian/control file instead of .travis.yml:

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 10.5.1),
               gettext,
               libgtk-3-dev (>= 3.10),
               libgranite-dev,
               libgcrypt20-dev,
               meson,
               valac (>= 0.28.0)
```

(Thanks, David)